# Windows Server 2016 restore users folder in documents

Tags: powershell, windows-server

I have created in Windows Server 2016 some users, with limited grants and specific group owned. Each user has a a validity period the expires periodically. These users access the OS via RDS and can use only one app that allows writing on a specific folder in user\documents.

As administrator I would like to restore that directory, deleting all users file created and copying some default files.

I can't do this apparently simple operation because I have do not have the permissions (I have administrator rights!). I also noted that if a user logs on and then logs off, I can access this folder and restore it.

Any suggestions?

PS. In the attached image I noted that User icon can change, and I wasn't able to understand why.

[image]

Comment: This is not a PowerShell issue or PowerShell resolution, as this is Windows security boundaries by design. Just because you are admin on Windows, really dose not mean you have full control over everything. Microsoft documents this. Depending on factors, sometimes you must take control of stuff before you can do anything to it, you being admin, does not change that. Even something as UAC when running as admin --- https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mrsnrub/2010/08/06/user-account-control-but-im-an-admin/

Comment: Well I still don't understand, because as administrator I own the XGuest(n) folder, I have full controll, but I can access it. If I go on the property page "Advanced Security Settings for XGuest(n)", I'm Owner and I effectivelly have full control! What I have to do? 
I'm a developer but for pratical reason I was forced to be a super user.